# getXidKey() returns null on API below 16. Android Xtify SDK GCM implementation

Tags: android, xtify

We have implemented Xtify SDK 2.1.0.2 and it works perfectly on API 16. 
If I run it on any AVD with API level below 16 it doesn't register and I don't get the xtify XID.

```
XtifySDK.start(getApplicationContext(), XTIFY_APP_KEY, SENDER_ID);
XtifySDK.getXidKey(getApplicationContext()); // returns null
XtifySDK.isNotificationEnabled(getApplicationContext(); // returns true
```

We re-checked the implementation guide and nothing seems to be missing.
We even added the GSM library on the project but didn't help.

Is there something else I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've confirmed the sample app is working OK for API Level 8.  You'll need to setup an AVD with Target Name Google APIs (not Android), API Level 8.  You must also make sure to add your gmail account after your AVD launches.

Comment: Great thanks Michael. The problem was that we didn't have the Google Account set on the AVD (seems to be not needed on the avd with Google API 16). 
Also, after testing the Sample App we noticed that we had some "receivers" commented on the Manifest.